# How to get Updates from a service released in a separate process

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service

I have intent service that has been released in a separate process due to some reasons I have also made service in a way that it can not be killed by the android OS until and unless it is explicitly stop by the user using the GUI button on the activity.

Every thing is working fine. I am updating my notification area with the progress of downloading status, See the following method in service.

```
void publishProgress(int progress) {
    mBuilder.setProgress(100, progress, false);
    mNotifyManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
}
```

it is updating the notification with the current downloading status.  On download complete I have made the callback , which hides the stop button on the activity once the downloading is completed.

Now I want to show the downloading status in activity also , that shows the percent of downloading that has been completed so far (same I has shown in notification area so I will used that method)

**So how can I update and send call back to activity as when the 1 percent is complete Until it is completed.**

So any idea how to do such kind of real time update.

Comment: You can use broadcast receiver to send the update to the activity, or you can use Handler. refer [this example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/handler/android-handler-example/)

Comment: you have to use AIDL http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

Comment: If your service is in a separate process you have to use Android Inter process Communication (IPC) follow these links http://codetheory.in/android-interprocess-communication-ipc-messenger-remote-bound-services/ and http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html.

Comment: I am trying one thing more , can you guys tell me how to send the int , in Bundle , as here I am sending the empty Bundle in the function I have posted above. 
receiver.send(STATUS_UPDATES, Bundle.EMPTY);